# Prepared mysqli statement not working on new cpanel hosting

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel, web-hosting

Previously I had a Linux hosting package for my website and had the following code

```
$selectUsersStmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT firstName FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$selectUsersStmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$selectUsersStmt->execute();
$result = $selectUsersStmt->get_result();
```

It worked fine on the Linux hosting but since switching to CPanel it is now giving a commands out of sync error after the 3rd line.

Is there something in the way I need to prepare my statements that is different with CPanel vs Linux?

Comment: What code have you got before this? This doesn't look possible. Maybe you have it configured to use libmysqlclient instead. Check your CPanel if you have mysqli_nd enabled

Comment: I have a require file which is creating the $connection variable. I know this is working as other queries are fine with the same require. 

In terms of mysqli_nd I can see the following are ticked in CPanel (mysqli and mysqlind) however nd_mysqli is not ticked. Is that how it should be?

Comment: I have unticked mysqli and now have both mysqlind and nd_mysqli ticked and the code is working again!! Thank you @Dharman. If you want to post that as the answer I will mark as correct. Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, I meant nd_mysqli. I added proper answer now.